# Jackson reading all numbers as BigDecimal

Tags: java, json, jackson

We are using Jackson to read json from the filesystem and parse it to the POJO.

**POJO**

```
String name;
Map<String,Object> map;
getters/setters
```

**Reading**

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.USE_BIG_DECIMAL_FOR_FLOATS);
Pojo obj = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, Pojo.class);
```

**Problem**

When we have numbers in json (map part) they gets converted to *Integer* Or *Double*.And we want all our numbers (decimal and whole) as Type *BigDecimal* So I tried using the

> mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.USE_BIG_DECIMAL_FOR_FLOATS);

But this only works for the decimal numbers. There is no feature available to covert whole numbers to BigDecimal.

Question

1. Do we have any inbuilt feature to enable ObjectMapper to read all the number to BigDecimal?
2. If I need to write custom serializer, Do I need to write it for the whole class or it can be written for Map field ?

Comment: Is `USE_BIG_INTEGER_FOR_INTS` close enough?

Comment: HI,
Thanks for the quick response I tried using that but it converts number to BgInteger where as we want BigDecimal.

Comment: Indeed.  Out of interest, why do you *need* them to be BigDecimal?

Comment: Actually these fields would be rather big scientific number with precision of 16

Comment: Sure, but if they're actually integer values, then `BigInteger` would be sufficient for any number of digits.

Comment: No actually they could be full numbers or they could be decimal numbers.

Comment: If you really need a `BigDecimal` in the end, `BigDecimal` has a constructor that takes a `BigInteger` argument (actually four such constructors). Requires some hand coding, though.

Comment: What I am saying is: why does it matter if some of the values are `BigDecimal` and some of them are `BigInteger`?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth With `Map<String, Object>` it becomes problematic if you intend to aggregate fields by key or lists because you can't do a binary operation a `BigDecimal` and a `BigInteger`. You would need to do as @ole-v-v says 'hand coding'.

Comment: @PrachitRaorane I know it's been a few years but I encountered this at work today and I have a solution for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can register a `Module` with your `ObjectMapper` that includes a custom `JsonDeserializer`. You don't need to make your own because Jackson Databind provides a [BigDecimalDeserializer](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.13/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/std/NumberDeserializers.BigDecimalDeserializer.html) but you need to do one more thing to make it work.

Because BigDecimalDeserializer is annotated with `@JacksonStdImpl`, Jackson won't allow you to use this directly because the initialization code (I currently disagree with this) [specifically checks for this annotation and disallows it](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/2.14/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/std/UntypedObjectDeserializer.java#L160).  Because this deserializer is not a `final`, you can get around this without copy-pasting by creating an anonymous subclass.

In the end, it will look something like this

```
Module module = new SimpleModule();
module.addDeserializer(Number.class, new NumberDeserializers.BigDecimalDeserializer() {});
new ObjectMapper().registerModule(module).readValue("{}", Map.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `:BigDecimal:[dps]` is in your json. For example :

```
{
  "MY_BIG_D:BigDecimal:0" : 3
}
```

where dps = decimal places.

Comment: how does this help?