# How can I configure Jackson to use BigDecimal when parsing numbers?

Tags: java, json, jackson

When using Java and jackson-databind.jar file (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.14.2) I'm finding the last fractional digit of a 17 fractional digit number is lost, so I'm only getting 16 fractional digits after parsing the JSON string.

For example:

```
{
   "myval" : 0.09345678901234567
}
```

is stored as `0.0934567890123456646023214489105157554149627685546875` (based on debugger).  To test this I wrote some simple Java code:

```
        String string17Digits = "0.09345678901234567";
        double double17Digits =  0.09345678901234567;
        BigDecimal test17Digits1 = new BigDecimal(string17Digits);
        BigDecimal test17Digits2 = new BigDecimal(double17Digits);
        BigDecimal test17Digits3 = new BigDecimal(0.09345678901234567);
```

When I examine these values inside the debugger, I see the problem.
[image: Debugger showing values]

So my belief (not yet proven) is that somewhere in Jackson-Databind when the JSON is being converted from a string to a number value a `double` datatype is being used to store the number.

I'm searching for a way to configure Jackson to use `BigDecimal` as the underlying datatype when converting strings to numbers.

## Searching for solution

1. What is the precision for a Java `double`?
   [See theserverside.com article](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/Java-double-precision-2-decimal-places-example-float-range-math-jvm), [JavaSE article](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3) and [Java datatypes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) - These articles while helpful didn't answer my basic question. **How many fractional digits of precision can I get in a number less than 1?**
2. A google search for the answer [says this here](https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/plain-html/topics/impala_double.html):

> Precision: 15 to 17 significant digits, depending on usage. The number of significant digits does not depend on the position of the decimal point. Representation: The values are stored in 8 bytes, using IEEE 754 Double Precision Binary Floating Point format.

3. Searching for a way to configure Jackson to use BigDecimal to store numbers that have been read when creating the internal NodeTree representation.  I found [Jackson reading all numbers as BigDecimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44408254/jackson-reading-all-numbers-as-bigdecimal)

I'm thinking this last one is the answer to my question so I'll check it out.

Comment: ‘The number of significant digits does not depend on the position of the decimal point’: this is most certainly incorrect. The quoted significant figures only applies to values without a fractional part. Fractional values can have arbitrarily more significant digits.